# How to insert var b into button name

Tags: php, jquery

```
<button type="submit" name="" id="bbb" value="" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-check"></i>Confirm</button>

$('#mymodal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
var btn = $(event.relatedTarget)
var a = btn .data('aa')
var b = btn .data('bb')
var modal = $(this);
modal.find('#bbb').val(a);
});
```

how to insert var b into button name= (here)

Answer (score 2):

Use the `attr()` method:

```
attr("name", b);
```